# Solve a triangle given the two angles in which a median split a vertex angle

Tags: triangles, angle, median

Given the two angles $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ in which a vertex angle of a triangle is split by the related median $m$, find the remaining angles of the triangle $\beta$ and $\gamma$.

[image]

I encountered this problem in my research, I think that it is well defined and definitely solvable, but I cannot find the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By applying the sine law for triangles $ABM$ and $AMC$, you can get that $\frac{sin \alpha1}{sin \alpha2} = \frac{sin \beta}{sin \gamma}$ holds true. Since problem statement indicates the given angles $\alpha1$ and $\alpha2$, using triangle's angles summation property, one would find $\gamma = 180 - \alpha1 - \alpha2 - \beta$ with known ratio $\frac{sin \beta}{sin (\alpha1 + \alpha2 + \beta)}$. I guess it would be obvious afterwards to evaluate the desired angle $\beta$.

Comment: You can find relevant posts about median sine laws in the following link: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-sine-law.html

Comment: Sure, the sine theorem! I wouldn't say that it is *obvious* to solve the resulting transcendental equation, however somehow Wolfram Alpha returns a closed form which seems to work: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+sin%28x%29%2Fsin%28a1%2Ba2%2Bx%29%3D+sin%28a1%29%2Fsin%28a2%29+for+x

Comment: @DarioP I guess median sine law just overkills the problem, along with returning sine ratio where angles were dependent only on $1$ angle, and that was equal to well-known value.